# How can I auto-format text pasted into rich textbox?

Tags: c#, fonts, textbox, formatting, richtextbox

I have a notes program that I use to document cases while working, however when I copy and paste data from other windows it pastes it in with the formating from the site. Is there a setting for rich text boxes (and text boxes in general) that will remove any formatting and put only the text into the textbox? If not can do I have to use a method that looks at the clipboard contents and sends the string to a specific font/size etc?

Comment: You could write you own method and have it call on maybe the double click event. Or you could even do 'Ctrl + V' combo key press event.  There is no setting for RTB's that remove formatting.   When you say formatting, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: I mean that when you copy something that is big and bold letters on a website, then paste it into the form it still has big bold letters, I would like it to be a standard text, not big and bold. Sounds Like I'll have to make a method to format it.

Comment: Like Magnus said below, save the capture the clipboard to a string or Var, then move the string over to your richtextbox. That should work. --Testing now--

Comment: That works. I did not have a problem with the formatting being carried over when storing the clipboard data into a string, then over to the RTB. If your going to use the event, and need help with a complete method, np just ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get the unformatted string by specifying the [TextDataFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textdataformat.aspx) and set it to `Text`:

```
var stringToPasteIn = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Text);
```

Or letting the `RichTextBox` do it for you automagically using its [DataFormats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/23kah9ca.aspx) options:

```
DataFormats.Format myFormat = DataFormats.GetFormat(DataFormats.Text);
richTextBox1.Paste(myFormat);
```

Comment: This will work, but I think the harder problem is detecting when a paste has occurred.  See this SO article to help you with that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618162/detecting-if-paste-event-occurred-inside-a-rich-text-box

Comment: I dont think he is needed to detect when the paste occurs. Alternatively, the OP could simply contorl when the paste occurs; as in on the richtextbox Double click event etc...Thats what I would recommend.