# In Idle cannot access RichTextControl or IME will not work

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, rtf, ime

When reading some `RichTextControl` properties inside `Application.Idle` some IME won't work.

Given this simple code:

```
_richTextControl = new RichTextControl();
Application.Idle += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    btnCopy.Enabled = _richTextControl.SelectionLength > 0;
    btnPaste.Enabled = _richTextControl.CanPaste();
};
```

It'll work fine with most IME I tried but, at least, for *Chinese (Traditional, Taiwan)* with *Microsoft Chinese Traditional Array (6.0)* and *Chinese Traditional DaYi (6.0)* it'll prevent IME to work properly (I tried only with Windows 7, in English and Taiwanese). You can start typing but when  `Idle` code is executed (reading `SelectionLength` property and invoking `CanPaste()` method, here I wrote them both but each one is enough to reproduce this) it'll stop working (you type but pop-up window is closed immediately and nothing is sent to `RichTextControl`).

I checked MSDN about `EM_GETSELTEXT` and `EM_CANPASTE` but it says nothing about this issue. I also tried to replace `SelectionLength` property manually sending `EM_GETSELTEXT` with `SendMessage()` but it doesn't change this odd behavior (however I checked WordPad - which uses rich editor - and it works properly even if (AFAIK) MFC commands use idle time to update UI status).

Of course I can move some code into `SelectionChanged` event and update UI both from `Idle` and from `SelectionChanged` (and it'll work) or I may update some *flags* in `SelectionChanged` and change UI in `Idle` but this will break existing code and it'll force a big change in UI library (all commands have not knowledge of `Idle` or `SelectionChanged`, they simply return true in a `CanExecute()` method when their target control allows their execution). If nothing else is viable then I may derive a class from `RichTextControl` to make these methods/properties callable in `Idle` (using flags updated elsewhere) but (to avoid a big refactoring) I would know if it's a knows issue, a bug related to IME itself or if there is something else I missed.

Comment: You referenced this question in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10122762/2592875) that was referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45760744/2592875).  Anyways, have you tried using the [Text Object Model (TOM)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787607(v=vs.85).aspx) interfaces to access this info?  I don't have the setup to test it, so I don't know if it would work.  It may be worth a try if you are still looking for a solution. Another thought is that maybe related to the RTB using the old RichEdit20W class vs the RichEdit50W class.

Comment: @Tn I don't work on that any more but I should give it a try, I never found a _good_ solution for this. Thanks!