# Is there selection text event in text box

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm creating a little text editor(just like notepad).I have a few buttons on my form(cut, delete, copy). I want them to be unable when there's no text selected and vice versa...Is there some event that happens when the text is selecting? I use text box control.

Comment: What control dou you use for working area?

Comment: if using a [rich text box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/647963/windows-forms-selectionchanged-event-for-textbox-class) is an option, you will have such an event.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is not such event but fortunately there are workarounds:

1) Do it by your own updating UI on `Application.Idle` event (I admit this isn't best solution but it's more often than not my favorite because it's easier to implement):

```
Application.Idle += OnIdle;
```

And then:

```
private void OnIdle(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    btnCopy.Enabled = txtEditor.SelectionLength > 0;
}
```

2) Derive your own class from `RichTextControl`  (not best solution if you have to handle huge - not just big - files) and handle `EN_SELCHANGE` notification (most robust one also compatible with every IME I saw around). Proof of concept (pick proper values from MSDN and don't forget to set `ENM_SELCHANGE` with  `EM_SETEVENTMASK`):

```
public class TextBoxEx : TextBox {
    public event EventHandler SelectionChanged;

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
        base.WndProc(ref m);

        if (m.Msg == WM_NOTIFY && m.lParam == EN_SELCHANGE) {
            OnSelectionChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

You might do it but...default control already has this feature for you: it has a `SelectionChanged` event.

Be careful if you also support clipboard pasting because you need to update your paste button according to clipboard content (then easier place is again in `Application.Idle`). Calling `CanPaste()` and similar methods on `RichTextControl` may break some IMEs ([see also In Idle cannot access RichTextControl or IME will not work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27600031/1207195)).

Answer (score 3):

If you use `RichTextBox`, there is a property called `SelectedText`. You can check if the `SelectedText` is not empty:

```
if (richTextBox1.SelectedText.Length > 0){ //means there is a selection
}
```

Combine it with `SelectionChanged` event:

```
private void richTextBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    bool enabled = richTextBox1.SelectedText.Length > 0;
    //do something
}
```

You could control to enable/disable your `Control` when there is/isn't selected text.