# C# Mix font for richtextbox .

Tags: c#, fonts, richtextbox

I try make a text editor application, but I have issue about Font of richtextbox.
phenomonon as bellow:
I coppy Text and paste into wordpad, and set font for wordpad is "Verdana",if font no support text wordpad auto change font to "Malgun Gothich", look so beautifull.

[Text on wordpad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyN4p.png)

But when paste this text in to my app. My app has one Richtextbox Control. Font of Richtextbox is "Verdana", but font of richtextbox mixed between "Verdana" and "Gulim", look so bad.

[Text on my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7zSJ.png)

How to solve this issue, how to show text on my app look like wordpad ?

Thanks all,

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [detecting-if-paste-event-occurred-inside-a-rich-text-box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618162/detecting-if-paste-event-occurred-inside-a-rich-text-box)

And use below code to update font of text

```
rtbData.SelectAll();
rtbData.SelectionFont = this.Font; // You must change font which you want here.
```

Comment: Which event of richtextbox did you use? How do you create your Font object?